# Which button pressed in flowlayoutpanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, event-handling

For my current project I am adding an variable amount of `usercontrols : ucTask` to my `flowlayoutpanel : flpTasks`

```
foreach (task t in tasks)
{
   ucTask uct = new ucTask();
   uct.id = t.task_id;
   uct.date= t.date.ToString();
   uct.btnNaam = t.task_id.ToString();

   uct.OnButtonclick += new EventHandler(uct_OnButtonclick);

   flpTasks.Controls.Add(uct);
}
```

[image: ucTask]

Now I will have a couple of those usercontrols in the flowlayoutpanel, and I want to fire an event when I press that button. With the `EventHandler` I can fire an event, but I need to fire a different event for a different button.

```
    void uco_OnButtonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "TEST";
    }
```

I don't know how to know which button (or usercontrol) I pressed. And I'm out of ideas, any suggestions?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sender of event is actually one of buttons. When you cast sender to Button type, you can access any of Buttons properties and determine which button was pressed:

```
void uco_OnButtonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button button = sender as Button;
   if (button == null)
       return;

   lblStatus.Text = button.Name;
}
```

UPDATE: after reading your question once again, I get that ucTask is actually UserControl, which rises event when button inside it was clicked.

So, first is naming. Good style for class names in c# is PascalCase. E.g. for task user control good name will be `TaskControl`. Next goes event naming. It's common to name events as `EventName(-ing, -ed)`. If you want to raise event, then good style is protected method `OnEventName(-int, -ed)`. And another remark - when you writing user controls, you are free to use business terms to name your events. E.g. TaskCreated, TaskChanged. And you also can pass any parameters to your event by creating custom EventArgs.

So, for your user control:

```
public class TaskChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public TaskChangedEventArgs(int taskId)
    {
        TaskId = taskId;
    }
    public int TaskId { get; private set; }
}

public class TaskControl : UserControl
{
   public event EventHandler<TaskChangedEventArgs> TaskChanged;

   // raise it inside button click event handler
   protected void OnTaskChanged(int taskId)
   {
       if (TaskChanged != null)
           TaskChanged(this, new TaskChangedEventArgs(taskId));
   }
}
```

When you use your user control, just subscribe to its TaskChanged event:

```
uct.TaskChanged += new EventHandler<TaskChangedEventArgs>(uct_TaskChanged);
```

And all parameters, that you passed via event argument will be available in that event handler:

```
void uco_TaskChanged(object sender, TaskChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = e.TaskId.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! I was having errors at first, because my `button` isn't actually a `button`, it's a `picturebox`. Once I thought of that I got it all working, Thanks!
(Is there a good alternative for buttons if you want to use your own image?)

Comment: @ThomasSchoof plase check my update. There is some design recomendations for your :)

Comment: Wow thanks, that are some very helpful tips which I will be sure to utilise in my projects. I'm not going to rename my usercontrols for this project because I have named all my userscontrols: ucName and my forms: frmName.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the sender should be the user control right? Then you can cast and determine the item through `ucTask.id`.

```
void uco_OnButtonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucTask uc = sender as ucTask;
    lblStatus.Text = uc.id.ToString();
}
```

This presumes that the `OnButtonclick` event of the user control sends a reference to the user control and not a reference to the pressed button as the sender of the event.

Comment: Actually, he has the same answer as I do ;-)

Comment: I know - I was just kidding. You are free to accept any answer you like :-D